# Unable to restore SEC filings preloaded database from arelle.org, postgres pg_dump gzip file

Tags: database, postgresql, restore, pg-dump

I was trying to restore an SEC form preloaded database from Arelle.org using postgres. Below is the link:
http://arelle.org/documentation/xbrl-database/

It's the one towards the bottom of the page where it says "Preloaded Database".
I was able to download the file, but unable to gunzipped it at first. So, I copied the file and renamed it with `.gz` extension instead of `.gzip`. Then, I was able to gunzip it, but noot sure if that affects the file.

After that I tried the following command on postgress to restore the database in the database that I created:

`psql -U username -d mydb -f secfile.pg`  (no luck)

I also tried:

`pg_restore -C -d mydb secfile.pg`   (also no luck)

I am not sure if it's because I copied and renamed the file. But, I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: Renaming does not matter. But is a (19GB) gzipped file, you should first try to see what is in it: `zcat yourfile | less`

Comment: It looks like a (gzipped) plaintext -SQL dump. There is no `create database thisdb;` at the start, so you should do that yourself. (as user+owner postgres). Then, you should submit the big file via `zcat the_file | psql -U postgres the_db_that_you_just_created`